# SQL Server create a full field select fast

Tags: sql-server, select

When writing a statement

```
select * from tableName
```

you get all the fields, however I want to get all the fields in the statement for better code, is there a tool to do it faster in SQL Server, to get

```
select f1,f2,f3 from tableName
```

which are all the fields in tableName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the management studio you can drag-drop the columns-node from the table into the query.

Comment: +1 Wow, that`s even more comfortable than my suggestion to use query editor in SSMS

Answer (score 1):

The [SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Prompt/index.htm) add-on by Red-Gate Software has this functionaliy.

You type:

```
SELECT *(caret here) FROM dbo.YourTable
```

and then you press the `TAB` key - and voila, the list of fields from that table is inserted instead of the `*`

And of course, SQL Prompt does **a lot more** too! Great tool, absolutely essential for me - use it all the time. Well worth the product price!

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS, right click the table -> Script table as... -> SELECT to... New query editor window

That'll do the trick

Answer (score 0):

in sql server management system

- right click on the table
- "script table as"
- "select"
- "new query windows"

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server Management Studio, if you right click on the table you can create script for simple instruction (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) and also to alter the table definition (CREATE, ALTER, DROP)